# List and text concatenated inside input

Tags: python, list, variables, text, concatenation

In my Python code(Which I am unable to show as an image because rep<10), I am trying to make a program which asks the user's name, and then guesses their age from 1 to 30. For some reason, the line starting "AgeQ =" (L16) does not work, as it 'Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly'. Below is the error in the code and error log etc., help would be much appreciated.

```
 AgeQ = 'Are you ' + Age[x] + 'years old? (Y/N)'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\rhs-vmw-p-fs01\students\2010\R07972\Python\test2.py", line 16, in <module>
AgeQ = 'Are you ' + Age[x] + 'years old? (Y/N)'
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

Answer (score 4):

You can cast the int to a string explicitly:

```
AgeQ = 'Are you ' + str(Age[x]) + 'years old? (Y/N)'
```

or, better, use string formatting:

```
AgeQ = 'Are you %s years old? (Y/N)' % Age[x]
```

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason the code still does not find the correct number in the list, instead just uses the 2nd (1) item.

Comment: Then you have the wrong value for `x`. Show more code (but even though you now have 10+ rep, don't use an image... that's annoying to read and copy to try it out ourselves. paste the code into the question and click `{}` with it highlighted...)

Comment: Name = input('Hello, what\'s your name?')
print(Name)

Next = 'Oh, hello ' + Name + ', \nhow are you?'
print(Next)

FirstLetter = Name[0]
ThirdLine = FirstLetter + ' for ' + Name + '!'
print(ThirdLine)

AgeA = 'N'
while AgeA == 'N':
    x = 0
    int(x)
    Age = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]
    AgeQ = 'Are you ' + Age[x] + 'years old? (Y/N)'
    AgeA = input(AgeQ)
    if AgeA == 'N':
        x = x + 1
        
    
    
print('So you are ' + Name + ', and you are ' + Age + 'years old?')

Answer (score 3):

```
AgeQ = 'Are you {age} years old? (Y/N)'.format(age=Age[x])
```

You can not concatenate a string with an int, you must either convert the int to a string, or format it somehow.